# enabling local group policy through script

Tags: batch-file, scripting, group-policy

We are experiencing some problems when signing in to Onedrive, we found a fix with a policy. Now I want to make a script to deploy it to other customers.

I tried adding a key to te registry to enable te policy:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002" /v Functions /t REG_SZ /d TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA384,TLS_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256
```

However, when I run this script, it doesn't enable the policy in gpedit.msc.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running the batch file elevated? _it needs to be 'Run as administrator' to modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry keys_.

Comment: If you do not want to re-start console as administrator, use gSUDO https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo

Comment: Yes i used administrative rights for the scripts. The scripts reported that it suceeded. the keys are visibale in regedit. the only problem is that the policy stil is not configured in gpedit.

Comment: You'd probably need to restart the system or force a refresh of the registry data, if you're expecting the entries to show up immediately in the GUI.

Comment: If the modification is visible in regEdit, then your code does the job (update registry).